# How to round a decimal output to two places?

Tags: java, android, formatting, decimal

In this program I'm printing a value from a calculation of type `double` to the screen.But at present the calculation is giving 14 decimal places.My question is,is there a facility in Java to wrap the output statement in that could specify the amount of decimal places?For example `round(mark1,2)`

[image]

The way it is printed at present is like this:

```
 double markOne = intent.getDoubleExtra("number1", 0);
 result1.setText(String.valueOf(markOne)+"mm");
```

Is it possible to wrap the `setText` in a Java method or would I have to create a custom format?Could someone give me an example of this with my code? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a decimal formatter

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
System.out.print(df.format(d));
```

Comment: thanks,I'm just going to test now like this:  `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
       
        result1.setText(String.valueOf(df.format(markOne)+"mm"));`

Comment: That worked a charm,I was getting a lot of suggestions for convoluted custom methods earlier,when all I had to do was use `DecimalFormat`

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better to use BigDecimal type instead of Double.
You could do

```
BigDecimal myValue= new BigDecimal(12.3577);
  myValue= myValue.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

And myValue will be 12.36

I hope this will help

Comment: +1 for using Rounding modes and BigDecimal to do proper rounding

Comment: @Pracede How do I apply this to my code,I'm a bit confused?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  int decimalPlaces = 2;
    markOne = double(int(markOne*Math.pow(10, decimalPlaces)))/Math.pow(10, decimalPlaces);
```

Comment: Now you're just being fancy.